How to expose different Github repos to different AWS accounts?
this is my scenario:

Github organization: Only one organization hosting multiple repos for different clients
AWS accounts: Each client have their own AWS account

I want to set up CodePipeline to build a CI/CD pipeline in their different accounts, so I have to connect their accounts with my repos. I'm usign the Github V2 connector recommended by AWS.
When trying to set up CodePipeline, the github integration wants to create a "AWS Connector for GitHub" Github app that is created at ORGANIZATIONAL LEVEL, and not repo-level.
I do have the ability to only export certain repos to that connector, but, all different AWS accounts usign that connector can see all the repos that are exposed through the connector, meaning, codebase from client A will be exposed to AWS account from client B.
I've browsed around and found that I can create "custom" github apps that expose the codebase content and install those apps INDIVIDUALLY to each repo.
However, when trying to connect CodePipeline with Github, it always tries to set up the "AWS Connector for Github", and it won't let me pick a custom app.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

After some research, it appears this is how the integration works, and there's no way around it. I ended up using github actions to deploy my code into AWS, instead of using CodePipeline.

Why not having one organization per client. We try to avoid multiple organizations, but your use case is a perfect match for that. If all client's repositories have to share code from your repo, simply create your organization, transfer shared repositories to it, allow everybody from your
enterprise (or you don't have github enterprise license ? ).
This way, you're able to install a AWS Github Connexion App on each organization with client specific authentication.
